# Getline problem

Tags: c++

I've got following code:

```
system("CLS");
string title;
string content;
cout << "Get title." << endl;
getline(cin,title);
cout << "Get content." << endl;
getline(cin,content);
```

The problem is - application is not asking about tittle, I've got Get title, get content and then waiting for user input, it's not waiting for user input after get title.bDo I have to add any break or smth?
Or maybe, that isn't the best idea to read whole text line from user input?

Comment: Why don't you just write `cin >> title` easily?

Comment: @Mr. TAMER If the title has a space in it, doing the `cin >>` will only get the characters up to a space.

Comment: Hello, erkses, welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for posting code so that we can see what you are talking about. In future, when posting code, please consider reducing your program to the minimal **complete** example that demonstrates your problem. In this case, I fear that you have excluded information critical to answering your question. For more information about how and why to post complete programs, see http://sscce.org.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `cin >> something;` call prior to your `system()` call.

For example, taking input into an integer.  When `cin >> myintvar;` (or similar) then the integer is placed in `myintvar` and the '\n' gets sent along in the stream.  The `getline` picks the `\n` up as indicative of the end of a line of input, so it is effectively "skipped".

Either change the `cin >>` to a `getline()` 
or call `cin.ignore()` to grab the `'\n'`(or better, call a `cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );` to flush the input buffer-- but be sure you're not throwing away valuable input in the process).

Comment: ignore before getline(cin,title); works, thanks!

Comment: @erkses no problem.  You'll run into this again, so watch for it :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet that you have something like a menu for selecting options ( as a numeric type ) and after that you try to read the lines.

This happens because after std::cin read some value the remaining '\n' was not processed yet, the solution would be to include `#include <limits>` and then put `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');`
 before your `getline(cin,title);`

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you use getline() it ignores the newline at the end of the line and feeds it into the input queue, so when your getline function is called for next time it encounters the newline character discarded by the previous getline() and so it considers that as end of your input string. So thats why it doesn't take any input from you. You could use something like this

```
getline(cin,title);
cin.get();
```

hope this works.

Comment: No, `getline` reads the entire line and discards the newline. The problem here is something else.